# PG::UndefinedFunction when calling from Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am using ruby 2.2.6 and rails 4.1.16, with pg as database.

I am getting the PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR : Operator does not exist. timestamp without time zone > time without time zone.

I know this is due to the comparing of different datatype, so I need to change the dataype from the query itself.

I tried looking around and found this [guide](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-5-attributes-api) but it is for rails 5. and another probable solution is to use cast in the sql query.

My query is:

```
normal = Staff.joins([department: {profils: :schedule_times}], :time_loggers).where(department: selected_departments, status: 1, schedule_times: {day_state: 1, day: wday}, time_loggers: {daterec: date}).where("time_loggers.timein > schedule_times.bstart")
```

I tried modifying the query by adding a cast to the sql,the query works but didn't return the intended result.

```
normal = Staff.joins([department: {profils: :schedule_times}], :time_loggers).where(department: selected_departments, status: 1, schedule_times: {day_state: 1, day: wday}, time_loggers: {daterec: date}).where("cast(time_loggers.timein AS TIME) > schedule_times.bstart")
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT

Actually the query with cast works and returned results, the problem is actually the datacontent.

If I switch the operator to be < as in
`where("cast(time_loggers.timein AS TIME) > schedule_times.bstart")` then it gives me some results.

time_loggers.timein is `Wed, 05 Jan 2022 09:05:00 +08 +08:00`
schedule_times.bstart is `2000-01-01 09:00:00 UTC`

Now the problem changed already i guess. I need to change the data content directly in the sql before comparing those data, is it possible? Because I need to avoid using each to iterate then compare, as I have thousand of records so the website will be very slow.

What I want is to get those data in my timezone, GMT+8 then only get the hour and minutes and do the comparing.

Or maybe should I post this as another topic?

Comment: I update the post. The new problem is bstart is in UTC but timein is in GMT+8

Comment: Pg has the ability to set up default casts, but I generally avoid doing it, as I prefer stated rather than implied casts. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html you also have the ability to `date_trunc` in order to compare date or time components https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work the query.

```
normal = Staff.joins([department: {profils: :schedule_times}], :time_loggers).where(department: selected_departments, status: 1, schedule_times: {day_state: 1, day: wday}, time_loggers: {daterec: date}).where("to_char(time_loggers.timein + interval '8 hours', 'HH24:MI' > to_char(schedule_times.bstart, 'HH24:MI')")
```

I converted both timein and bstart using postgres `to_char` and added 8 hours into timein match the bstart, as it is in GMT+8 using `+ interval '8 hours`.

Special thanks to jad for giving the appropriate direction, that pg documentation is very helpful.